# Why is there more space after single line table?

Tags: formatting

This is a simplified code which reproduces the issue. I compile it with:

```
pdflatex --halt-on-error test.tex
```

There are multiple tables placed one after the other with the `dual` command. When the content is single-line, then the vertical space after the table is larger than when the table row has multiple lines:

```latex
\documentclass [
    12pt, twoside, openright
] {memoir}

\newcommand\dual[2]{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X}
        #1 & #2 \\
    \end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}

\dual{
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
} {
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
}

\dual{
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
} {
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
}

\dual{
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
} {
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
}

\dual{
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
} {
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

What is the reason? How can I make the space the same? I know I could use a negative vspace for such tables, but that solution requires to always check the number of resulting lines, therefore it's not acceptable.

Comment: Put a `%` after `\end{tabularx}` to remove the spaces. Then it's all equal.

Comment: @dexteritas Thanks it worked! If you write it as an answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: I can put it to an answer later, but let's wait if someone gives also the reason for this behavior.

Comment: Add `\par` after  `\end{tabularx}` to remove the spurious space.